# How to set persistent keyboard layout for X Windows in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard-layout

I want to set permanent Japanese keyboard layout for X Windows in Kali Linux (Rolling Edition 2016.1, testing with `kali-2016.1` Vagrant box).

Setting Japanese keyboard manually through **All Settings** -> **Region and Language** -> **Input Sources** works ok and is persistent. I want to provision the same settings through a script.

---

For ad-hoc configuration I run:

```
setxkbmap -layout jp
```

which works until user logoff. It does change the layout, however it does not add/change **Input Source** in settings panel.

---

For persistent configuration I tried the following (with no success):

- I created directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` with the following content:

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
          Identifier "system-keyboard"
          MatchIsKeyboard "on"
          Option "XkbLayout" "jp"
          Option "XkbModel" ""
          Option "XkbVariant" ""
          Option "XkbOptions" ""
  EndSection
  ```

  But it has no effect.
- I tried running:

  ```
  localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap jp
  ```

  which supposedly should create `00-keyboard.conf`, but although it ends with no error, it does not create the file.

Settings for console work ok (Japanese layout is active when typing username at the logon screen). My `/etc/default/keyboard` is:

```
XKBLAYOUT=jp
BACKSPACE=guess
```

And I have also setting in `vconsole.conf`:

```
KEYMAP=jp106
```

---

How can I set persistent keyboard layout from CLI?

Comment: did you actually mean `localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap jp`?